# How do I use koma-script on Overleaf?

Tags: spacing, koma-script, paragraphs, overleaf, line-spacing

I'm mostly self-taught in LaTeX and currently flailing around trying to use it for a math class. Which is to say, I probably don't know very much of the jargon and I may be approaching things totally backwards (please tell me if there's a better approach!).

I read that koma-script has good typography settings, which I'd like (particularly paragraph/line spacing, margins, and indentations), so I downloaded it to my computer. I tried uploading the whole folder (after unzipping) to a project in Overleaf, but that did not seem to work. How can I use koma-script on Overleaf?

Comment: It should work if you just use ```\documentclass{scrreprt}``` or whichever KOMA class you want to use in your document, no need to upload any additional files to Overleaf if I remember correctly

Answer (score 3):

Koma-script is part of every tex distribution and already on overleaf you should not have had to download or unzip anything or add any files to your overleaf project

Here is an overleaf project to get you started

https://overleaf.com/read/tmtksjzdfjsw

That link may  not be good forever so a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Well, don't I feel silly now. =P Thanks!

Comment: @Emmett there are no silly questions, it takes a while for the various bits of the system to "sink in"  when you start,